# phantom.exit() runs immediately when it's used with async.waterfall()

Tags: asynchronous, phantomjs, async.js

I have a set of URLS that I want `PhantomJS` to visit and save them as html in parallel, using `async.map()`. Given that I must close the page I opened to free RAM, I believe I need to use page.close(). I did that.

However, I also want to exit Phantom when it's done, and I tried to achieve this adding by `async.waterfall()`, but it exists immediately.

How can I do this right?

```
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");

var urls = [
  {"url": "https://www.google.com", "html": "google"},
  {"url": "http://yahoo.com", "html": "yahoo"}
];


async.waterfall([

  function (callback2) {

    async.map(urls, function (a, callback) {
      var resourceWait = 300,
        maxRenderWait = 5000,
        url = a.url;

      var page = require('webpage').create(),
        count = 0,
        forcedRenderTimeout,
        renderTimeout;

      page.viewportSize = {width: 1440, height: 900};

      function doRender() {
        var content = page.content;

        var path = '../public/html/' + a.html + '.html';
        fs.write(path, content, 'w');
        page.close();

      }

      page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
        count += 1;
        clearTimeout(renderTimeout);
      };

      page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
        if (!res.stage || res.stage === 'end') {
          count -= 1;
          if (count === 0) {
            renderTimeout = setTimeout(doRender, resourceWait);
          }
        }
      };

      page.open(url, function (status) {
        if (status !== "success") {
          console.log('Unable to load url');
        } else {
          forcedRenderTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            doRender();
          }, maxRenderWait);
        }
      });
      callback();
    });

    callback2(null, 'done!');
  }
], function (err, result) {
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`async.map` requires a callback as the third argument that can be called once all the parallel calls get finished. You need to call the `callback2()` inside that callback.

Your code currently just starts async.map and immediately calls `callback2()`. You should call it inside `async.map` callback.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");

var urls = [
  {"url": "https://www.google.com", "html": "google"},
  {"url": "http://yahoo.com", "html": "yahoo"}
];


async.waterfall([

  function (callback2) {

    async.map(urls, function (a, callback) {
      var resourceWait = 300,
        maxRenderWait = 5000,
        url = a.url;

      var page = require('webpage').create(),
        count = 0,
        forcedRenderTimeout,
        renderTimeout;

      page.viewportSize = {width: 1440, height: 900};

      function doRender() {
        var content = page.content;

        var path = '../public/html/' + a.html + '.html';
        fs.write(path, content, 'w');
        page.close();

      }

      page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
        count += 1;
        clearTimeout(renderTimeout);
      };

      page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
        if (!res.stage || res.stage === 'end') {
          count -= 1;
          if (count === 0) {
            renderTimeout = setTimeout(doRender, resourceWait);
          }
        }
      };

      page.open(url, function (status) {
        if (status !== "success") {
          console.log('Unable to load url');
        } else {
          forcedRenderTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            doRender();
          }, maxRenderWait);
        }
      });
      callback();
    }, function() {
        return callback2(null, 'done!');
    });
  }
], function (err, result) {
  phantom.exit();
});
```